# the Sobolev spaces via Fourier tranform

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $s\in R$ . Consider the classical definition :

$$H^{s}(R^n) = \{  f \in S^{'}(R^n) /  (1 + \|   \theta \|^2)^{s/2} \hat{f} \in L^{2}(R^n)  \}.$$

My book says $\widehat{(H^s (R^n))}$" = $L^2({R^n} , (1+|\theta|^2) d \theta)$. The inclusion $\widehat{(H^s (R^n))} \subset L^2({R^n} , (1+|\theta|^2) d \theta)$ is immediate. But i dont know  prove the another part. Someone can give me a hint ?

Thanks in .